# webpack bundle created which version of node/npm?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have upgraded my node and npm paths to node 8 and npm 5. But I am not sure whether bundle created by webpack used node 8 and npm 5 or the earlier version.

Is there a way to identify which version of node and npm was used by webpack to create bundle of an application?

Comment: For an existing bundle file I'm not sure. But if you can run your build again, just open your webpack config file and somewhere at the top write `console.log('node version: '+ process.version)` to print the node version to console.

Comment: And what about npm??

Comment: Well, I don't believe npm has direct influence to your bundles output. But if you could build your bundle again, and the `process.version` output is the same as typing `node --version` in your console, you may assume that when you type `npm --version` this is the version that is currently installed and used throughout the process. Does that make sense?